# Make sure string contains only certain words with regex

Tags: java, regex

I want to validate that a string is in the correct format using regex in Java. A string is in the correct format if the only words it contains are from a specified list. A word can contain upper case and lower case letters. The string can contain numbers and symbols.

For example, if my list of acceptance words is `[foo, bar]`, then the string

```
foo bar! bar foo.
```

is valid. Note that the string doesn't have to contain every word in the lsit. Thus the string `foo` is valid and the string `bar` is valid.

A string like

```
foo bar baz!
```

is invalid.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
/^(foo|bar|[[:space:][:punct:]])+$/
```

Comment: What are the [:space:] and [:punct:] expressions called? Just so I can google them. And you should also add a \d after punct since numbers should be allowed.

Comment: These are [POSIX character classes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#POSIX_character_classes)